# how to call validation function while saving data in database?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use  strong password in my program. So I searched for strong password validation but I didnt understand how to call that function while saving.

This is the function I want to use for password validation:

```cs
private bool ValidatePassword(string password, out string ErrorMessage)
{
    var input = password; 
     ErrorMessage = string.Empty;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        throw new Exception("Password should not be empty");
    }

    var hasNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
    var hasUpperChar = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+");
    var hasMiniMaxChars = new Regex(@".{8,15}");
    var hasLowerChar = new Regex(@"[a-z]+");
    var hasSymbols = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]");

    if (!hasLowerChar.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should contain At least one lower case letter";
        return false;
    }
    else if (!hasUpperChar.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should contain At least one upper case letter";
        return false;
    }
    else if (!hasMiniMaxChars.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should not be less than or greater than 12 characters";
        return false;
    }
    else if (!hasNumber.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should contain At least one numeric value";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!hasSymbols.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should contain At least one special case characters";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The save button  code:

```cs
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var data = DBConnection.DBConnect();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_Users", data);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StaffName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtStaffName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phoneno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPhoneNo.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Admin", SqlDbType.Char).Value = chkIsAdmin.CheckState == CheckState.Checked ? 1 : 0;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    MessageBox.Show("Saved Sucessfully");
    LoadUsers();
}
```

Can someone give me an idea how I can use this function to perform password validation, please?

Comment: I don't see any password column you are inserting while executing the store procedure. When exactly do you want?

Comment: ops i miss placed the button code sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I do not get the problem but it's that simple?:

```cs
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var error = string.Empty;    
    if(ValidatePassword(txtPassword.Text, error))
    {
        var data = DBConnection.DBConnect();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_Users", data);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StaffName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtStaffName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phoneno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPhoneNo.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Admin", SqlDbType.Char).Value = chkIsAdmin.CheckState == CheckState.Checked ? 1 : 0;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        MessageBox.Show("Saved Sucessfully");
        LoadUsers();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(error); // Or Console.WriteLine(error) or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: nth is wrong i just didnt know how to call the function thank you for your help

Comment: Okay, that was easy :D Would you mind to check this answer as correct one if it is the solution for your problem?